# Aggregate function along with unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate, unpivot

I am using unpivot function which is executed against on a temp table and it gives the result as shown below.

```
Select User, Grade, Experience FROM @TempTable
unpivot
(
  [Experience] For [Grade] IN ([L1],[L2],[L3],[L4])
) unpiv;
```

Output

```
  [User]  [Grade]   [Experience]
      1       L1        2
      1       L2        3
      1       L3        1
      1       L4        0
      2       L1        1
      2       L2        2
      2       L3        0
      2       L4        0
```

Beside experience column I would also like to have percentage column and that should be grouped by Users. For example if we consider User 1, for L1 grade it will be 2/6 *100 and for L2 it will be 3/6 * 100

Any suggestions on how to achieve?

It will be like Experience/Sum(Experience) * 100 but the SUM should be grouped by User.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. Most likely you'll have an easier time with a `VALUES` table construct over the more restrictive `UNPIVOT` operator.

Comment: `Experience / sum(Experience) over(partition by user rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)`?

Comment: @GSerg I didn't get how where and group by can be applied [Experience]/SUM([Experience]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Experience])* 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @TempTable table ([User] int, L1 int, L2 int, L3 int, L4 int);
insert into @TempTable([User], L1, L2, L3, L4)
values(1, 2, 3, 1, 0), (2, 1, 2, 0, 0);

Select [User], Grade, Experience, (Experience*100.0)/SUM(Experience) OVER(PARTITION BY [User]) 
FROM @TempTable
unpivot
(
  [Experience] For [Grade] IN ([L1],[L2],[L3],[L4])
) unpiv;
```